# toilet will not flush even after replacing the toilet twice

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I bought this house 5 years ago and have always had problems with the half bath toilet. It was very very slow to flush if at all. Now it will not flush at all. I have replaced the toilet twice with new toilets, one round and one long. Both 1.28 tanks and not low flow. I presently called a plumber because the sink also got clogged. He cleared the clog but the toilet still had issues. He opened the wall to find the sink went into a cross fitting. The sink in from the left, another sink from upstairs in from the right, the toilet seems to be on the bottom and at 2 in the vent that only went up about 12 inches and was capped. So time running short that day we put it all back together and I later got a vent valve, with a box on the wall for later access, and installed a 36 in 1 1/2 inch vent pipe on the top of that cross. Mind you the cross fitting is about even with the sink fixture. Now the sink works great now but the toilet still won't flush. We added a pipe to the tank so it will fill all the way up, still nothing. with the toilet off he inserted a water hose with a fitting and ran it for a long time, it drained to the septic fine (flow in the inspection hole outside was good). But once we reinstalled the toilet, same problem. Tank fills up and slowly does down and never really empties. If you put anything in it like toilet paper it won't even do that. It's as if it's starved for air or something. He did notice the line going into the septic, the inspection hole is about 3 inches higher than the toilet line. He measured with the toilet off. This is from the center of the house to the back corner so about 60+ feet, not sure if that's enough to warrant tearing into a slab foundation to replace plumbing.

that's where we are and their only idea is to install a sump pump or tear the floor up and add a bunch of 45s to try and help it. Any ideas or even questions we having thought to ask yet. I and my plumbers are lost... on my third plumber now. Help...

Comment: Force air into the pipe that the aav is on with a blow dryer or a small shop vac hose attached to blow side.   While air is being forced in flush the toilet.  If it flushed properly yiu now have evidence that the cause of your trouble is indeed air starvation.  1.5 is small for venting a toilet.

Comment: Investigate a [pressure assisted toilet](https://www.thespruce.com/how-a-pressure-assisted-toilet-works-4150402).

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please feel free to [edit] that wall of text into some paragraphs - it will make it _much_ easier for people to read. Once you've done that, take a minute to take the [tour] to learn how to get the most out of this site. It'll help kill time while waiting for an answer.

Comment: Is there now an air admitting valve 1-1/2” in a stud bay?  The vent at 1-1/2” for a toilet is the minimum I will use with a direct path to the outside.  if I read it correctly I do not think a toilet will ever flush properly until it is properly vented, a sink is a low flow device a toilet is a huge flow only exceeded by a washing machine in most homes. I might try Providing air as kris mentioned or opening the vent to see if the toilet will flush with the vent unobstructed. Bad venting can and will cause drains to clog as the liquid leaves the solids.

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I assume you snaked the main line?  If yes maybe a vent issue?  Or possibly the main vent is blocked somehow?